# How to prevent apps to become auto install without user interaction?

Tags: applications, default-applications, application-autoupdate, disable-app

In my mobile some app automatically install without my any action. Some times thos apps are auto install even I already uninstalled them, but every time I uninstalled thos apps are automatically install in my phone after few hours.
OS. 5.1
software which automatically install :- Reos message and music.

Comment: Please give examples and your OS version, device details

Comment: @beeshyams question update. Os.5.1 and Reos message is automatically install